Selenium SendKeys for iOS: Using the Left Arrow Key places a high five emoji instead of moving the keyboard cursor
When I use the Selenium Sendkeys() method for an iOS mobile application to move the cursor to the left, it instead places a high five emoji in the text field area. The code that I'm using is the following:
string libelle = "/XCUIElementTypeApplication/XCUIElementTypeWindow[1]/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther[2]/XCUIElementTypeOther[2]/XCUIElementTypeOther[2]/XCUIElementTypeOther[2]/XCUIElementTypeTextField";

Outil.Driver.FindElementByXPath(libelle).SendKeys(Keys.ArrowLeft)

I'm able to use the SendKeys() method to enter string values into the text field and the Keys.Enter key by doing this:
Outil.Driver.FindElementByXPath(libelle).SendKeys("Example" + Keys.Enter)

I'm not sure why I'm getting an emoji when using Keys.ArrowLeft. I have also tried the following code and I continue to get the same high five emoji:
Outil.Driver.FindElementByXPath(libelle).SendKeys(Keys.Left);
Outil.Driver.FindElementByXPath(libelle).SendKeys("\ue012");

What can I do to move my cursor to the left instead of getting the emoji?

I don't think .SendKeys() is intended to be used like that. It's intended to type text into an INPUT field, etc. I did some googling and found, https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/9853. Someone else was having the same issue and got an answer in another link.

@JeffC Thank you for the link! I found this link before, but I wasn't able to figure out how to fix this problem. I guess I'll have to keep searching.
